# I got this javax.el.ELException org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, primefaces

When i want to print an attribute of an othre object attribute of my formation Object in XHTM page i got an exception that there is an exception of `javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'intitule' on type model.Theme`, this is my code :

```
<h:form id="a">
                                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
                                <p:dataTable var="formationObject"
                                    value="#{formationBean.listformation}" id="AjoutTab"
                                    widgetVar="FormationTable" emptyMessage="Formation non trouvé"
 rows="15"


                                    style="width:500px;font-size:13px;margin-left: 0px">

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <p:outputPanel>
                                            <h:outputText value="Recherche:" />
                                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                                onkeyup="FormationTable.filter()"
                                                style="width:80px ;float:center " />
                                        </p:outputPanel>
                                    </f:facet>

                                    <p:column headerText="Intitule " id="formationRef"
                                        filterBy="#{formationObject.planning}" filterMatchMode=""
                                        footerText=" reférence exacte" width="15px">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{formationObject.planning.intitule}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column style="width:4%">
                                            <p:commandButton  value="Analyser"
                                                icon="ui-icon-search"
                                                action="#{formationBean.redirectModification()}"            

                                                ajax="false" title="Analyser" />
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable> 
                            </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LazyInitializationException` is a very common error, and it practically always mean you either don't fully understand hibernate proxies or don't control what where happens in your application.

When you use @OneToMany annotation, hibernate usually uses lazy loading. It means, in object, in place of collection, you have a **proxy**, than contains no element, and loads elements on first request (such as `get()` or `size()`).

However, if the collection is accessed outside the `Transactional` scope, which in web applications usually means EL methods, the hibernate session that is bound to the proxy doesn't exist anymore.

To prevent such behavior you can choose 2 ways:

1) Don't use `@OneToMany`. Instead, if you want a collection, provide a DAO method for loading that collection.

2) Make sure you never return object with lazy-loading proxies from DAO method. You can iterate through the collection, set it to null, or pass the DTO through mapper such as Dozer, that would call all getters and iterate through all collections, returning object free of proxies. You can also call `evict()` on hibernate session, but with iterating or setting null you are aware if the object was loaded or not.